# Analytic solution to 2 dimensional PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the 2D PDE
$$\frac{\partial p(\mathbf{x},t)}{\partial t}=-{f}(\mathbf{x})\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}p(\mathbf{x},t) -{g}(\mathbf{x})\frac{\partial }{\partial x_2}p(\mathbf{x},t)+a\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x_1^2}p(\mathbf{x},t)+b\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x_2^2}p(\mathbf{x},t)$$
so that I can test the accuracy of a numerical solver that I wrote. Here, $a$ and $b$ are real valued, nonzero, scalars.

I learned how to solve this when $f$ and $g$ are constants, but I am not sure if it is possible to analytically solve this when they are not constant (Or if one is nonconstant and the other is constant). I have been searching in the literature but am having trouble finding solutions.

Are there any known solutions to this that I can use to test my code in this situation that either $f$ or $g$ or both are nonconstant? Even for a specific case would be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Search for the method of manufactured solutions.
I would be very surprised if you can solve this analitical for arbitrary f,g.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definitely look into that.